# Custom scope in access token cognito user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

Here is my requirement: I have a cognito user pool which may include 2 seperated role: 1 for user and another for admin. I use amazon-cognito-identity-js [link here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js) to register user in my react native mobile app, and for admin I will add it manually. My problem is everytime I log in the mobile app, the access token always return the scope below

> aws.cognito.signin.user.admin

Is there any way to config when I register and login in my react native app, the access token will return another string?